# click-through is not working - is SetWindowLong the proper technique?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been struggling with this a lot and have looked at several stackoverflow posts that recommend this as the correct procedure:

[Transparent window layer that is click-through and always stays on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077236/transparent-window-layer-that-is-click-through-and-always-stays-on-top)

In my code, I'm following this technique almost exactly. And yet, my code is not working and I'm a little confused to why. I'm wondering if I'm using the wrong procedure? To be clear, my desired effect is for the user to click my form and to access something underneath it. For example, I am running  on top of visual studio. If I try to click the app, I click visual studio instead.

UPDATE:

When I call my code, one of two things happens (depending on where I call the setwindowlong method):

1. The window does not draw
2. The window draws, but is clickable

Option 1 happens when I run the code right after initializecomponent
Option 2 happens when I run it before initializecomponent

Here is the complete code to draw my form before anything else:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);

    public frmPhoneQueueViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set the form click-through
        int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
        SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);


        //Get height of taskbar to exclude it, then bind to lower right of screen
        int nTaskBarHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom -Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom;
        Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
        this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right - this.Size.Width, workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height + nTaskBarHeight);
        this.TopMost = true;

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;


        PopulatePhoneQueueData();
    }
```

Comment: Not related to the question but just wondering what happens if a user has his taskbar on the left/right/top rather than the bottom?

Comment: How doesn't it work? You should describe the details.

Comment: Check if `Handle` is already created. If I remember correctly, the windows handle is not created yet in the Form's constructor.

Comment: From the docs: "The CreateControl method forces a handle to be created for the control and its child controls. This method is used when you need a handle immediately for manipulation of the control or its children; simply calling a control's constructor does not create the Handle.
CreateControl does not create a control handle if the control's Visible property is false. You can either call the CreateHandle method or access the Handle property to create the control's handle regardless of the control's visibility, but in this case, no window handles are created for the control's children."

Comment: Also, from the Handle property docs: "The value of the Handle property is a Windows HWND. If the handle has not yet been created, referencing this property will force the handle to be created."

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20` which will make your form totally transparent.This extended style is required to make a `click through window`. So we would have some way to show your window normally (otherwise it's transparent and that's why you thought **it wasn't drawn**), we do this by using the win32 api function `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` (as declared in your code) or simply set the `Opacity` property of your form. By the way, you should override the `CreateParams` to initialize the extended style without declaring and using the methods `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong`. Here is the code which should work (at least solve your problem: **the window isn't drawn**):

```
public frmPhoneQueueViewer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //The default Opacity = 1 won't show your form
    Opacity = 0.2f; //or even Opacity = 0.999 if you like
    //....
    //....
}
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
         CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
         //WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000  WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20
         cp.ExStyle |= 0x80000 | 0x20;                
         return cp;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: There is an interesting thing here which I've discovered. If you override the `CreateParams` as the code above, `Opacity=1` won't show your form (totally transparent), you must change the `Opacity` to another value, for example `0.2` to make it partially transparent, even `Opacity=0.9999` will show your form (looks like 100% opacity). However if you use some `bool flag` to prevent initializing the styles in `CreateParams` and apply the styles later using `UpdateStyles()`, your form will show OK when the `Opacity=1`, the code looks like this:

```
public frmPhoneQueueViewer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //The default Opacity = 1 will show your form normally
    Load += (s,e) => {
        appliedStyles = true;
        UpdateStyles();//Call this to apply the styles to make your window able to click through.
    };
    //....
    //....
}
bool appliedStyles;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
         CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
         //WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000  WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20
         if(appliedStyles) cp.ExStyle |= 0x80000 | 0x20;                
         return cp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to set additional window styles is by overriding the [`CreateParams`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createparams.aspx) getter.

That way the styles will be present from creation.  `SetWindowLong` may set them too late to be 100% effective.