# Overlay transparent window catching touch events

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a 3D software designed to be used with mouse and keyboard.
In order to make it "touch screen compliant" I would like a custom transparent window over it capturing touch events.
This window should capture touch event, and let the underneath window still having mouse events.

I can have a not click/touch-through window (obviously ^^)

I can have a click/touch-through window ([Transparent window layer that is click-through and always stays on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077236/transparent-window-layer-that-is-click-through-and-always-stays-on-top))

But I am unable having both.
If my window is click/touch-through, it becomes useless, it can not detect touch event.

Maybe letting my window managing all touch/mouse/stylus event, filter what I want, and pass mouseDown/Up/Move/... to my software ?

Is it possible ?
Thanks