# Transparent Window with Clickthrough and on Top

Tags: c++, dll, game-maker

I am currently working on a small overlay project in Game Maker that I want to always render on top, have a transparent background, and allow clickthrough to the window behind it. Using GML extensions and a DLL has worked for the transparent background part, although nothing I have tried for the rest have worked.

Using `SetWindowPos` for `HWND_TOPMOST` or calling it with `HWND_TOP` every time it get minimized has seemingly no effect.
This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077236/transparent-window-layer-that-is-click-through-and-always-stays-on-top) seems to be close to what I am looking for, except I do not need the DirectX rendering as Game Maker should do that for me, and I do not think it will connect with the GML extension that I need it to.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <dwmapi.h>
//[DllImport("User32.dll")]
//#include <User32.dll>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DLLMakeWindowTransparent2(HWND hwnd) {
    //get HWND from Gamemaker
    //makes the background of the gamemaker window transparent, this works fantastically
    MARGINS margins = { -1,0,0,0 }; 
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins);

}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DLLMakeWindowTop(HWND hwnd) {
    //should force the window to always display on top, but hasnt worked
    //SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
}
```

Comment: In my extension ([itch](https://yellowafterlife.itch.io/gamemaker-window-commands) / [git](https://github.com/YAL-GameMaker/window_commands/tree/master)) I am implementing topmost as `SetWindowPos(hwnd, enable ? HWND_TOPMOST : HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);` and that works just fine - perhaps you have additional factors here? Also, this doesn't seem to be C#

Comment: I tried using the same syntax as your extension, and it still freezes the game window for a few seconds then crashes, giving the "exited with non-zero status (-1073741819)" error. You are also correct in that it was not C#, that was a labelling error on my part and it has been corrected. 

Also forgive me in not knowing much about downloading gml extensions, I attemped to download your extension, pointed the extension to the window_command_hook-for-GMS2.3+, added a function of window_set_topmost with 2 string arguments (hwnd and true/false), and no crash, it was not topmost window.

Comment: If you are downloading the repository, you'll need to compile it first. There's a pre-compiled version on itch io