# How do I get in C# an Aero like transparent window that can be clicked through

Tags: c#, aero

What I want to do is to make an external application (process) go TopMost Aero like tranparent that can be clicked through. The problem is that I can get Aero to work or a TopMost click through window but not both.
The commented part of the code (/*DwmApi... */) is the Aero code wich also removes the title bar of the process window and underneath is the code for the click through window ( I don't need alpha set if I have Aero on, here it is used for testing purposes).

Here is a link that shows what Aero code does:
http://ru11en.wordpress.com/category/mikumikudance/

And here is a link for the clicking "through" code:
[Topmost form, clicking "through" possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524035/topmost-form-clicking-through-possible)

Note that if I change GWL_STYLE=-17, the program doesn't remove the title bar anymore.

```
 //GWL_STYLE=-16; GWL.ExStyle=-20;
 private void transparency_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessItem selectedItem = (ProcessItem)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                IntPtr handle = selectedItem.Handle;
                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
```

`/*DwmApi.DwmExtendIntoClientAll(handle);
                int num = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
                SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, num);
                SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP__REFRESH);
              */
                int wl = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL.ExStyle);
                original = wl;
                wl = wl | 0x80000 | 0x20;
                SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                SetWindowLong(handle, GWL.ExStyle, wl);
                SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, 0, 200, LWA.Alpha);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Actually I can have both transparency and click through but I had to place the code in 2 separate buttons.