# How to draw rectangle over web browser

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to draw over a web browser object, but it is not displaying. It displays on the form, but refuses to display over the browser. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim frameWidth As Integer = Me.Size.Width
    Dim frameHeight As Integer = Me.Size.Height
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Blue)
    Dim graphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim WithEvents htmldoc As HtmlDocument

Private Sub htmldoc_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs) Handles htmldoc.MouseMove
    x = e.MousePosition.X
    y = e.MousePosition.Y
    Dim rectangleOne As Rectangle = New Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100)
    graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangleOne)
End Sub

Private Sub webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles webBrowser.DocumentCompleted
    htmldoc = webBrowser.Document
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for all your help mates!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I draw a rectangle over a PDF page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995950/how-can-i-draw-a-rectangle-over-a-pdf-page)

Comment: Thank you! The solution from the other question worked like a charm! Surprisingly, I was searching for about an hour and didn't come across this solution. Thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , **graphics can't write on an html document and on a web browser**.
You can make it with an external html file , but without graphics .
Add this code to your project :

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("index.html")
'The browser select your html file
```

**Create an html file named "index.html" in the executable file directory** and write this on it :

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <Title>Rectangle</Title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="rectangle_style">

  </div>
  <style type="text/css"> 
  .rectangle_style {

  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 600px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #0AC6EC;

  }
  </style>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I hope it helps you