# Disabling click through of form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Using the code i've retrieved from here : [VB.net Click through form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294658/vb-net-click-through-form) , i finally get "the click through of form" working but i'm still confused how to disable the click through.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private InitialStyle As Integer
Dim PercentVisible As Decimal

Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitialStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20)
    PercentVisible = 0.8

    SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle Or &H80000 Or &H20)

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * PercentVisible, &H2)

    Me.BackColor = Color.Red
    Me.TopMost = True
End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetLayeredWindowAttributes")> Public Shared Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal crKey As Integer, ByVal alpha As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

End Class
```

i know the disable is probably within these 2 codes, but i can't get it working, any kind of help will be greatly appreciated :

```
Public Sub BlaButton_click (blah blah) handles bla bla
        SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle Or &H80000 Or &H20)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * PercentVisible, &H2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Using a Const declaration for magic numbers is generally wise.  You wouldn't have accidentally used -16 that way and probably would have seen that you reset the style by only using InitialStyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i've solved it myself, i just need to erase some parameters.

The code before

```
SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle Or &H80000 Or &H20)
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * PercentVisible, &H2)
```

i just need to remove the "WS_EX.Transparent" value , in this case the value is &H20, so i removed "Or &H20"

and the other thing is to remove the "PercentVisible" multiplier, i removed 
"* PercentVisible"

The code after

```
SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle  Or &H80000)
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255, &H2)
```

then it works like charm now.